# Как открыть диалоговое окно?

Tags: google-apps-script

Через Лист в Google Таблице перехожу в редактор Google Script ввожу следующий код:

```
function myFunction() {
  showAnchor('Vus', 'https://google.com');
}

function showAnchor(name, url) {
  var html =
    '<html><body><a href="' +
    url +
    '" target = "blank" onclick="google.script.host.close()">' +
    name +
    '</a></body></html>';
  var ui = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui, 'demo');
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Script')
    .addItem(1, testNew)
    .addToUi();
}
```

Доступ к Таблице и скрипту мне предоставлен. Сохраняю, перезагружаю страницу.
Возвращаюсь на лист в Таблице, привязанной к скрипту, рисую овал и назначаю скрипт, перезагружаю всё.

При различных небольших модификациях выводит три варианта:

1. В листе Не появляется имя скрипта рядом с меню СПРАВКА
2. Скриптовая функция не найдена (проверял имя соответствует скрипту, скрипт привязан к таблице)
3. [Со временем, иногда] открывается окно demo, но в нём не удается связаться с сайтом

В чём тут проблема?

Comment: У вас код невалидный.

Comment: Напрягитесь на доку https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/menu#addItem(String,String) Два стринга, Карл! Два!

Answer (score 0):

Замените

```
.addItem(1, testNew)
```

на

```
.addItem("myFunction", "myFunction")
```